# Borderless Windowed in Elementary

Tags: window-management

I have desperately been trying to find away to remove the window decoration of a specific window for a borderless windowed effect. There are lots of answers and systems out there for doing it but I have had no luck getting them to work in ElementaryOS, is this possible?